# Get Series with lowest value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df:

```
   a      b       c
   d  e   f   g   h   i
a  12 13  23  5   3   13
b  5  43  31  31  41  76
c  14 13  4   24  20  12
```

I want to get the series that contains the lowest value, so in this case `df[('c', 'h')]`. How can I code this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `stack` with `idxmin`:

```
df[df.stack([0, 1]).idxmin()[1:]]
```

Result:

```
a     3
b    41
c    20
Name: (c, h), dtype: int64
```